# Godot push notifications at specific time

Tags: firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, godot4

I am using Godot 4 for making a app. In the app, I want a head of a administration(or someone specifically)  to have the permission to change a time in the app which changes the firebase project's firestore's time. and when the time comes like 4pm or 5pm etc.. I want every device that have installed my app to ring to send a push notification.

for this, I think using python to check every minute if the current time is the time that is in the app, and if it is, it reaches to FCM(firebase cloud messaging) and sends a push notification to all users. I want to use "PythonAnywhere" for this. I dont if it will work or not it is a completely different story.

Currently, I want to subscribe to a topic in every device so that i can send push notification later to them. in GdScript. And turns out I am idiot and I cant do it.

If you want anymore info about this please inform me!
If anyone as a suggestion for this please let me know!

I tried to use Native Addon but it spits this error whenever I try to enable the plugin in Godot 4 : Unable to Load addon script from path: "res://addons/NativeLib/plugin.gd".